# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x9a44a2e8 in tid 19935 (GLThread 3723)

Tags: android, libgdx, segmentation-fault

Im using libgdx to make an android game. The game was working fine but then after after adding this line the app started to randomly close. 
`game.debugRenderer.render(game.world,playerCamera.combined);`

The game does have bodies that are being destroyed in the render loop but its at the end of the loop . All that the logcat is showing is

```
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x9a44a2e8 in tid 19935 (GLThread 3723)

    [ 07-23 18:09:09.086   299:  299 W/         ]
    debuggerd: handling request: pid=19890 uid=10268 gid=10268 tid=19935
```

Application terminated.

I dont know where to start debugging. The app crashes at random interval, frequently(not always) when the player body is destroyed. Sometimes the ground tile just moves at random and then the app crashes. I dont know what the error is and where to start from. If required i'll post the github link. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not deleting physics body when physics world is in the middle of a time step. You aren't allowed to destroy anything while Box2D is doing the simulation step.

```
if(!world.isLocked()){
    // delete body
}
```

Comment: This did not work. I'm getting the same error. The app closes at random, usually after destroying an object. I think the program is trying to reference bodies that have been destroyed. But I cannot find why... when destroying I first remove the **object** from the active list and put its body it in an Array<body> list containing bodies to be destroyed, the object is removed for the active list and put in a pool to be called later.(bodies are destroyed at the end of render and the bodies are removed from the list after doing so).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with the texture I was importing. All of the coding was fine. Replacing the image with another file seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you say what was the difference between both textures?

Comment: The texture was not rendering properly,, I don't know why.. They only differed in size and it wasn't even that big,, about 600x512. I guess the file wasn't compressed properly.